# Why is this array compared to two values instead of one?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble understanding what this bit of code means. Why is y.values compared to a tuple with two values, when the shape of the array is a single row (650,)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('readonly/mushrooms.csv')
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df)

df3 = df2.sample(frac=0.08)

X = df3.iloc[:,2:]
y = df3.iloc[:,1]


pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pca, y, random_state=0)


plt.figure(dpi=120)
plt.scatter(pca[y.values==0,0], pca[y.values==0,1], alpha=0.5, label='Edible', s=2)    # < --- why is y.values compared to two values instead of one???
plt.scatter(pca[y.values==1,0], pca[y.values==1,1], alpha=0.5, label='Poisonous', s=2)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Mushroom Data Set\nFirst Two Principal Components')
plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC2')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually y.values is a single row. In `pca[y.values==0,0]`, it is obtaining the values which satisfies `y.values==0` condition.

Please see the [fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform) documentation. It outputs a 2-dimensional array.